# How to integrate Python trained ML model into Node.Js

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to integrate trained python Machine learning model into Node.Js platform to predict the labels for text prediction on frontend.

**Converted the trained ML output .h5 file format into .json format**

Trained the machine learning model in python environment. Created an HTML file , Now I am trying to create an frontend where an input text data needs to undergo the model prediction and gives the output.

What have been done so far :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/form.html'));
});

const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');

const model = tf.loadLayersModel('C:\Users\Desktop\cate\model.json');
```

How I can move further so as to predict the output from the input text using the trained model